# Xamarin MasterDetail page update to new page

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

In my MainPage I have a MasterDetailPage.Detail with displays the default homepage. On the homepage I have three button that I want to pass a variable base on what button was click to the searchpage. When I click the button a get a blank page.

> Is this the correct way to update the MasterDetailPage.Detail?

MainPage.xaml

```
<MasterDetailPage.Detail>
    <NavigationPage>
        <x:Arguments>
            <pages:HomePage />
        </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>
</MasterDetailPage.Detail>
```

HomePage.xaml.cs

```
private void ButtonA_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    string key = "A";
    App.Current.MainPage = new MainPage { Detail = new NavigationPage(new SearchPage()) };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/bpjohannessen/XMD1

This uses the MVVM approach. In this example you have only one command that passes a CommandParameter.

Answer (score 2):

you already have a `NavigationPage` loaded inside of `Detail`, so you should use it to navigate to the next page

```
private void ButtonA_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    string key = "A";
    Navigation.PushAsync(new SearchPage(key));
}
```

Comment: what about passing the variable ?

Comment: your example wasn't passing anything either.  How does SearchPage expect to receive that variable?

Comment: updated example to show passing data via constructor

Comment: Don't forget to catch that value in the constructor of your new page oh by the way, your approach breaks the mvvm pattern Xamarin relies on

Comment: @SergioAMG Xamarin relies on MVVM?

Comment: @SergioAMG What do you mean it relies on MVVM?

Comment: According to Xamarin documentation MVVM is the pattern you need to follow for separating the views from the data itself. Not using the pattern leads to poor develop applications difficult to maintain and expand. You may want to take a look at the documentation.